# Is there a gem or a quick way to render some prawn code as an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, pdf, prawn

I'm looking for a way to re-use my prawn code in other views (HAML). It can also be an image, but I don't need the whole PDF (with the layout and other pages), just a small graphic (chart) that I render in Prawn using a method.

EDIT:
because I'm using Heroku and I'm not saving the file (it's a response to a web request), I'm don't really want to open a pdf file with ImageMagick for example and process it into an image, unless it is my last option (besides coding the graphic again in HTML+CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a gem that might do the trick but you can always use RMagick or MiniMagick to covert the generated pdf to an image and scale it down:

```
require 'RMagick'
pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("doc.pdf")
image = pdf.scale(300, 300)
image.write "doc.png"
```

Hopefully you'll find this useful.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this possibility, but because I'm using Heroku and I'm not saving the file (it's a response to a web request), I'm leaving this out as a last resort. The code seems pretty short though, so I might give it a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Even on Heroku you can still save stuff in your tmp folder, but yes - such a solution is less than ideal.

Comment: I guess this is the best way to do it momentarily. Thanks for the quick answer :) I'd wish though people built smarter PDF manipulation libraries that can share code with other view libraries and use a more html/css approach to designing PDFs